# SqlPackage Quiet Output SSDT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a script that automates the creation of a database on a CI server, however, the output of SqlPackage.exe is very noisy. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), there is a /Quiet:True flag to prevent this, however, setting this flag doesn't seem to make any difference. Does anyone know a way to make this work?

Here's the Command I'm running:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DAC/bin/SqlPackage.exe" /Quiet:True Action:Publish /SourceFile:<snip>.dacpac /Profile:<snip>.publish.xml /TargetConnectionString:<snip>
```

Comment: Noisy? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: As in I get a whole load of debug information printing to the console which ends up in my build log. EG. the line Creating Permission appears hundreds of times.

Comment: Why not just run the package as an Agent job?

Comment: Interesting, do you mean have a job on the db server that I can somehow trigger from my CI server to reconstruct the database?

Answer (score 1):

That sqlpackage setting doesn't do anything, unfortunately. Would it be possible to launch another console using cmd.exe and passing the sqlpackage call to it as an argument?

In any event, I recommend logging a Connect bug regarding that flag being ignored. Connect bugs for sqlpackage.exe can be filed at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)"

Comment: Thanks, bug filed at: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/1005462/quiet-flag-in-sqlpackage-exe-doesnt-do-anything

Comment: Microsoft Connect has been retired. Is there a way of following the progress of this issue or submitting a new one ?

Comment: Sql Server UserVoice is here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server

Comment: For me, it was sufficient to suppress all output, so I appended " | out-null" to the end of the sqlpackage.exe call and it was very quiet. =) That was sufficient for me. HTH you.